# By ref or value for NSMutableArray - (void)addObjectsFromArray?

Tags: objective-c

you cannot add/remove objects from a NSArray because it is immutable.  But you can update one of the objects.

In contrast NSMutableArray can add/remove objects and has an addObjectsFromArray method which takes in an NSArray as an argument.

Are the objects now in the NSMutableArray originally in an NSArray by reference or value?

Meaning if I update a property of an object in an NSArray that was previously passed to an NSMutableArray, will the object in NSMutableArray see that change and vice versa?

Comment: In very few cases (I can't think of any offhand) is an object copied when being "put into" some sort of Cocoa aggregate object.

Comment: Good to know I'm new to objective-c and that's the kind of thing I'm still adding to my mental model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` or `NSMutableArray` stores the references of objects.
In your case **Yes** changes will be reflected as `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are having the reference of same object.

Comment: But if you have an NSArray that is a copy of an NSMutableArray, removing/replacing an object in the mutable array (vs changing the contents of the object) will not affect the NSArray.

Comment: @HotLicks you are absolutely right, adding/removing object will not affect one another.

Comment: Technically the members of the array are passed by value (copied), but as noted above those array members are not your objects, just pointers. It helps me when working with arrays, dictionaries, etc. to remind myself that I'm working with a collection of pointers to objects, not a collection of objects.